# How can a boolean expression depend on evaluation order and assignment?

Tags: php, boolean, variable-assignment, operator-precedence

When I evaluate [the expressions below](http://codepad.org/Hb4LYgvc), the result is completely different depending on the evaluation order and whether I assign the value or not:

```
$a = true;
$b = false;
var_dump($a and $b); // false

$c = $a and $b;
var_dump($c); // true

$d = $b and $a;
var_dump($d); // false
```

I'm completely stumped. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=` has higher priority than `and`. So `$c = $a and $b;` is the same as `($c = $a) and $b;`, value of $a is assigned to $c. This is different from `&&` which has higher priority than `=`, so `$c = $a && $b` evaluates to `$c = ($a && $b)`;

Comment: I found this out myself just now. It seems strange, though. Is it like this in many other languages? I don't remember it from anywhere else.

Comment: I don't remember seeing it either in other languages. It can be used as short circuiting so in `$c = $a and $b`, $b evaluates only if $c=$a is true. Personally I'm trying to avoid such stuff, but it's quite common `$res = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$c = ($a && $b);  // will fix the problem
```